# Laravel mix.js() using absolute path after publicPath is set

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

My Folder hierarchy from document root is -

```
/
|- private/
|- private/webpack.mix.js
|- public/
|- public/assets/*
```

I've set my public path to -

```
mix.setPublicPath('../public/assets/');
```

And I'm then compiling and extracting the default laravel scripts -

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', '/js/app.js')
.extract([
    'vue',
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
]);
```

My Absolute path to the public directory is -
`/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/myweb.xyz/public`
And `vendor.js`, `manifest.js` and `app.js` are being in the public path but as such -
`/public/assets/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/myweb.xyz/public`

Is this an issue with mix or am I doing something wrong?
I only have a problem with `mix.js()`, everything else works as expected.

Comment: Solved: I had to replace mix.js() with scripts() and sass/styles()